# Showing that the matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling to understand the proof of the following question:
Let U(n) be a set of unitary  matrices(diagonalizable) .
Let F ⊂U(n) be an  abelian subgroup of U(n)
show that the matrices in F are simultaneously diagonalizable?
Please who can give me a simplified explanation of the solution, because I have found the solution in the internet but i do not understund it.

Comment: I think this is essentially ["commuting unitary operators are simultaneously diagonalizable"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57140/43949).

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a more general result:

*A set of diagonalizable endomorphisms that commutes are simultaneously diagonalizable*

See [Simultaneously diagonalisable iff A,B commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675559/simultaneously-diagonalisable-iff-a-b-commute) that can be easily extended to any set of diagonalizable endomorphisms.

Then apply it to your particular case.

In short: this has nothing to do specially with unitary matrices. Apart for sure that those are diagonalizable!

Answer (score 0):

The key point is the following: let $E$ be a finite dimension vector space over some field $K$, and let $F$ a set of endomorphisms from $E$ such that they all commute and they are all diagonalizable.

Then they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Proof: induction over the dimension of $E$. 
If $E$ is either zero or a line, it works. 
Assume the result is true as soon as $E$ has dimension lower than $n \geq 2$ for some integer $n$.

If $F$ contains only scalar endomorphisms, it works.

So assume there is $u_0 \in F$ that is not scalar, let us denote $U_i$ its eigenspaces. Since $u_0$ commutes with all the other elements of $F$, they all induce endomorphisms in all the $U_i$.

Since all the other elements of $F$ are diagonalizable, each one of them vanishes some polynomial with simple roots, thus this polynomial is vanished by all the resteictions to the $U_i$.

Let $F_i$ be the set of all restrictions of the elements of $F$ to $U_i$. By the induction hypothesis, the elements of $F_i$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, thus (concatenating goods bases for all $U_i$), the elements of $F$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Note that a similar proof works in infinite-dimensional spaces when $F$ is finite.

Comment: I try to read the solution many time but I can not undersand it.  As a biginner in this domain there are  so many details that I do not know about it in this solution.Can you please give me a detailed solution to this question, how did you get to these results?

Comment: What would you want me to detail?

Comment: I don't see why elements of F are simultaneous diagonalizable?

Comment: That is what I have been proving...