# Any transformation that commutes with a transformation commuting with $S$ must be a polynomial in $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finitely generated inner product space above $\mathbb{F}$. Denote by ${\rm End}\left(V\right)$ the space linear transformations $V\to V$.
>   For $A\subseteq{\rm End}\left(V\right)$ Denote $$C\left(A\right)=\left\{ X\in{\rm End}\left(V\right)|X\circ S=S\circ X\quad\forall S\in A\right\} $$
>
> For $S\in{\rm End}\left(V\right)$, denote $C\left(S\right)=C\left(\left\{S\right\} \right)$ and denote
>
> $${\rm Pol}\left(S\right)=\left\{ p\left(S\right):p\in\mathbb{F}\left[t\right]\right\} $$
>
> Show that if $S$ is diagonalizable then ${\rm Pol}\left(S\right)=C\left(C\left(S\right)\right)$.

I know that is $S$ has distinct eigenvalue then any transformation in $C(S)$ must be a polynomial in $S$, but apart from that I'm not really sure how to proceed.

One side I was able to do:

• $(\subseteq
 )$

Let $p\in\mathbb{F}\left[t\right]$, then $p\left(S\right)\in{\rm Pol}\left(S\right)$ and we need to prove $p\left(S\right)\in C\left(C\left(S\right)\right)$, that is, for all $T\in C\left(S\right)$ we want to prove that $p\left(S\right)\circ T=T\circ p\left(S\right)$. Let $T\in C\left(S\right)$. Then by definition $T\circ S=S\circ T$. Then $$p\left(S\right)\circ T=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}S^{i}\right)\circ T=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}S^{i}T=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}TS^{i}=T\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}S^{i}$$
 as required.

A bit stuck about the other side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commuting linear maps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84057/commuting-linear-maps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65012/if-matrices-a-and-b-commute-a-with-distinct-eigenvalues-then-b-is-a-po

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is not quite a duplicate of that. There is no assumption here that the minimal and characteristic polynomials are the same.

Comment: By the way: the term is *an inner product space **over*** $\Bbb F$, not **above**.

Comment: $C(C(S)) = Pol(S)$ is true for all $S$. No need to assume $S$ diagonalizable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom didn't know that. Thanks. English is not my native language

Comment: @orangeskid love to see a proof of the general case. As I'm still shakey on this specific case don't think I'll be able to prove it myself

Comment: The key to the general case is to note that when $S$ is simply a Jordan block, $C(S)=Pol(S)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of proof:** With an appropriate choice of basis, we can take $S$ to be a diagonal matrix.  That is, 
$$
S = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 I_{m_1} \\ 
& \lambda_2 I_{m_2}\\
&&\ddots\\
&&& \lambda_k I_{m_k} }
$$
here, $\lambda_i$ are the (distinct!) eigenvalues of $S$, $I_m$ is the $m \times m$ identity, and $m_{i}$ is the multiplicity of the $i$th eigenvalue.

First, find that $C(S)$ is the set of matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{A_1\\&A_2\\&&\ddots \\&&&A_k}
$$
where $A_i$ is an arbitrary $m_i \times m_i$ matrix.

Next, find that $C(C(S))$ is the set of matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{\mu_1 I_{m_1} \\ 
& \mu_2 I_{m_2}\\
&&\ddots\\
&&& \mu_k I_{m_k} }
$$
where $\mu_i \in \Bbb F$ are arbitrary.  It should be clear from this point that $Pol(S) \subset C(C(S))$ (though for you, this is unnecesssary).  For the reverse inclusion, it suffices to note that for any $\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_k$, it suffices to select an [interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) satisfying
$$
p(\lambda_i) = \mu_i \qquad i=1,\dots,k
$$

Comment: The key to going through the proof this way is a certain degree of comfort with block-matrix multiplication.

Comment: I keep putting discussion of the general case (not quite the style of this question) at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832

Comment: @WillJagy very nice. Feel free to add this answer to the collection if you find it sufficiently relevant.

Comment: That makes sense.. Had troubles using the fact S is diagonalizable, but this makes it doable for me.