# difficult question in my exam

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb C$ . What is the condition for which the commutant of the matrix is equal to polynomials in the matrix?

I proved that if the matrix is diagonalisable then the commutant of the matrix is equal to polynomials in the matrix (I mean $C[M]$ ), but is this the necessary and sufficient condition? If yes how to prove the reciprocal?

Comment: By $C$ you mean complex numbers? What are "polynomials in the matrix"? I suggest you edit your title to something that gives the essence of the question. " challenging question by my teacher " doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes it means complex numbers , the subject was edited :)

Comment: Maybe some punctuation...this insnt penelope.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/161233/253273)

Comment: Thanks sir I guess I need to say that the matrix must be cyclic