# If $S\circ T=T\circ S$, then $S$ and $T$ have a common eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Assume $S$ and $T$ are diagonalizable maps on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $S\circ T$=$T \circ S$. Then $S$ and $T$ have a common eigenvector.

I already have proof, but I just need validation in one part.
My proof:
Let $F$ be an eigenvector of $T$. This means $\exists \; \lambda \in R$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$. Then, using the fact that $S\circ T$=$T \circ S$, we have

$$ S(T(v)) = (S\circ T)(v)=(T \circ S)(v)=T(S(v)) \Longrightarrow T(S(v))=\lambda S(v)$$

Thus, $S(v)$ is also an eigenvector of $T$. So, $S$ maps eigenvectors of $T$ to eigenvevtors of $T$. Thus, $S$ must have an eigenvector of $T$.

How would one rigorously prove that if $S$ maps eigenvectors of $T$ to eigenvectors of $T$, then $S$ also has an eigenvector of $T$?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simultaneously Diagonalizable Proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof)

Comment: @MTurgeon: the *question* asked here is closely related yet not a duplicate of the question you've linked to.  However one of the answers also answers this question: this is a sort of gray area when it comes to closing duplicates.  My guess though is that this (extremely standard) question has been asked *on the nose* previously on this site.  Can you (or anyone else) find evidence for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've shown that the eigenspaces of $T$ are *invariant* under $S$. If $E_\lambda$ is the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $T$ inside $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it makes sense to speak of $S'=S|_{E_\lambda}: E_\lambda \rightarrow E_\lambda$. Then the key fact is that the characteristic polynomial $p'(T)$ of $S'$ is a factor of the characteristic polynomial $p(T)$ of $S$. Since $p(T)$ splits completely, so does $p'(T)$. In particular, $p'(T)$ has a root, corresponding to an eigenvalue of $S'$. That means $S'$ has an eigenvector in $E_\lambda$, but an eigenvector of $S'$ is simultaneously an eigenvector of $S$ and $T$.

To see why the characteristic polynomial of $S'$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $S$, note that $\mathbb{R}^n = E_\lambda \oplus \hat{E_\lambda}$, where $\hat{E_\lambda}$ is the direct sum of all other eigenspaces $E_\mu$ of $T$. Taking a basis of eigenvectors for $T$, and writing the matrix of $S$ with respect to this basis, we see that the characteristic polynomial of $S$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $S|_{E_\lambda}$ times the characteristic polynomial of $S|_{\hat{E_\lambda}}$.

Comment: +1: this works.  For some reason I prefer working with the minimal polynomial instead of the characteristic polynomial, although I'm having trouble explaining why this argument is any better than yours.

Comment: Also...the $\perp$ is a bit distracting, IMO.  The statement in question works over *any* field, whereas inner products don't work as well over an arbitrary field.  Also you don't really mean $\perp$, it seems to me; you mean what you say next, namely the direct sum of the other eigenspaces.  (This decomposition need not be orthogonal with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: @Pete: You're right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $T$ is diagonalizable then its minimal polynomial factors into distinct linear factors and the restriction of $T$ to any invariant subspace annihilates the minimal polynomial so this restriction is also diagonalizable since its minimal polynomial divides the minimal polynomial of $T$ and then also it factors into distinct linear factors.

We take $v$ in the eigenspace $E_\lambda(T)$ and we prove (as you did) that 
$$T(S(v))=\lambda S(v)$$
so $S(v)\in E_\lambda(T)$ and this means that $E_\lambda(T)$ is invariant by $S$ hence the restriction of $S$ to $E_\lambda(T)$ is an endomorphism and has an eigenvector which's a common eigenvector of $S$ and $T$.

Comment: Not every endomorphism of a finite-dimensional real vector space has an eigenvector, so this argument looks incomplete.  You need to explain why the diagonalizability of $S$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies that the restriction of $S$ to the invariant subspace $E_{\lambda}(T)$ has an eigenvector.  Do you know how to do this?  One argument uses the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I forgot to mention that my work is valid over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: "This proof is valid over an algebraically closed field" But unfortunately $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.  As I said your answer is easily completed by considering the minimal polynomial of a diagonalizable transformation and its restriction to a subspace.  Do you know how to do this, or do you want someone else to provide the details?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The assumption is that the endomorphism $S$ is diagonalizable so its restriction to any invariant subspace of $S$ is also diagonalizable. Isn't it?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I edit my answer. Is this your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I decided finally to leave my own answer, but I have upvoted yours.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for the comments. Just I would add one  comment to your  
gratifying answer: the case of semisimple transformation is *almost* similar to the case of non diagonalizable transformation over an algebraically closed field which's my first idea.

Answer (score 3):

Since I keep hinting that I want to see a certain answer, perhaps I had better just post it.

The OP has shown that for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, the $\lambda$-eigenspace $E_{\lambda}(T)$ is an $S$-invariant subspace: $S E_{\lambda}(T) \subset E_{\lambda}(T)$.  (This holds vacuously if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvector for $T$.  Henceforth let's assume it is.)  Thus we may consider the restriction of $S$ to $E_{\lambda}(T)$, and if we can show that this transformation has an eigenvector, it is both an eigenvector for $T$ and $S$.

Note that if the scalar field were algebraically closed (e.g. $\mathbb{C}$), then we would automatically have an eigenvector.  But since the given scalar field, $\mathbb{R}$, is not algebraically closed, this is not automatic: over any non-algebraically closed field $K$, there are linear transformations of $K^n$ (with $0 < n < \infty)$ without eigenvectors.  In fact the OP's assertion works over any scalar field $K$ whatsoever.

The key is the following claim:

> If $S: K^n \rightarrow K^n$ is a diagonalizable linear transformation and $W \subset K^n$ is an $S$-invariant subspace, then the restriction of $S$ to $W$ is diagonalizable.

For this I will use the following useful characterization of diagonalizable transformations.

> **Diagonalizability Theorem**: A linear transformation $S: K^n \rightarrow K^n$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial is squarefree and split, i.e., factors as a product of distinct linear factors.

For a proof, see e.g. Theorem 4.14 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/invariant_subspaces.pdf).

Now it is clear that the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $S$ to an invariant subspace divides the minimal polynomial of $S$ and that a monic polynomial which divides a squarefree split polynomial is itself squarefree and split.  So applying the Diagonalizability Theorem in one direction and then the other, we see that $S|_W$ is diagonalizable.

This completes the answer to the OP's question.  But actually it proves something much stronger: since each eigenspace for $T$ decomposes as a direct sum of simultaneous eigenspace for both $S$ and $T$, in fact all of $K^n$, being a direct sum of these spaces, also decomposes as a direct sum of simultaneous eigenspaces for $S$ and $T$.  Taking a basis of simultaneous eigenvectors diagonalizes both $S$ and $T$, so we've shown:

> **Theorem**: Let $S$ and $T$ be commuting diagonalizable linear transformations on a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space (over any field $K$).  Then $S$ and $T$ are *simultaneously* diagonalizable: there is an invertible linear transformation $P$ such that $P S P^{-1}$ and $P T P^{-1}$ are both diagonal.

Finally, recall that a linear transformation is **semisimple** if every invariant subspace has an invariant complement.  The following result shows that this is a "nonsplit version of diagonalizability".

> **Semisimplicity Theorem**: A linear transformation $S: K^n \rightarrow K^n$ is semisimple iff its minimal polynomial is squarefree, i.e., factors as a product of distinct (but not necessarily linear) factors.

This is also part of Theorem 4.14 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/invariant_subspaces.pdf).

From this result we can prove (in exactly the same way) the cousin of the first boxed result:

> If $S: K^n \rightarrow K^n$ is a semisimple linear transformation and $W \subset K^n$ is an $S$-invariant subspace, then the restriction of $S$ to $W$ is semisimple.

In contrast to the first result, I don't see how to prove this using the characteristic polynomial.  And in fact, the argument using the characteristic polynomial shows that the restriction of $S$ to any invariant subspace has an eigenvalue: it does not (directly) show that it is diagonalizable.  (In particular, recall that you cannot always tell whether a transformation is diagonalizable just by looking at its characteristic polynomial.  So in this sense the minimal polynomial is a "better invariant".)  So I think that I have now explained why I prefer this approach.