# Rank of Sum of Two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Prove if $AB = 0 = BA$ implies that $\text{rank}(A+B) = \text{rank }A + \text{rank }B$

Comment: What about $A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$? Then $\mathrm{rank}(A+B)=\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(B)=1$.

Comment: That is only one particular case.

Comment: Yes but that particular case is a counterexample AFAICT, so your statement is not true for all $A$ and $B$. Do you have some additional conditions on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Comment: This implies $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalizable, so you can use http://math.stackexchange.com/a/618319/197161