# If S is invariant under T then both are simultaneously diagnolized?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

My question is about the answer to another question on this site -

[Diagonalizable matrices that commute share eigenspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618288/diagonalizable-matrices-that-commute-share-eigenspace?rq=1)

I thought of leaving a comment but since it was a > 3 year old post, I thought I'd just ask a new question. In the answer provided by @user44197,

"Since the Eigen space of S is invariant under T and lets supposed $\lambda$ is an Eigen value of S with multiplicity m then,

$$M^{-1} T M = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   T_{1,1} & 0 \\
   0 & T_{2,2} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
"

Where $T_{1,1}$ is m x m.

I can't wrap my head around the reason for this. Why should the off-diagonal entries for $T$ become 0 when $M$ is a matrix that diagonalizes $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked answer assumes that $M$ is chosen so that $D=M^{-1}SM$ is diagonal with grouped eigenvalues. That is,
$$
  D=\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1 I_{m_1}&0&\cdots&0\\
    0&\lambda_2 I_{m_2}&\cdots&0\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    0&0&\cdots&\lambda_k I_{m_k}
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $S$ with multiplicities $m_1,\ldots,m_k$. Let $T'=M^{-1}TM$, and write $T'$ in block form (with the same size blocks):
$$
  T'=\begin{bmatrix}
    T_{11}&T_{12}&\cdots&T_{1k}\\
    T_{21}&T_{22}&\cdots&T_{2k}\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    T_{k1}&T_{k2}&\cdots&T_{kk}
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
  DT'=\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1T_{11}&\lambda_1T_{12}&\cdots&\lambda_1T_{1k}\\
    \lambda_2T_{21}&\lambda_2T_{22}&\cdots&\lambda_2T_{2k}\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    \lambda_kT_{k1}&\lambda_kT_{k2}&\cdots&\lambda_kT_{kk}
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
  T'D=\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1T_{11}&\lambda_2T_{12}&\cdots&\lambda_kT_{1k}\\
    \lambda_1T_{21}&\lambda_2T_{22}&\cdots&\lambda_kT_{2k}\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    \lambda_1T_{k1}&\lambda_2T_{k2}&\cdots&\lambda_kT_{kk}
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
But
$$
  DT'=M^{-1}STM=M^{-1}TSM=T'D.
$$
Since $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ for $i\neq j$, we have $T_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Its clear now - one point of confusion I still have - if all the $m_i$ are 1. This seems to imply that $T'$ will be diagonal as well? That can't be right.

Comment: That is right. If $S$ and $T$ commute then $T$ must preserve the eigenspaces of $S$. If all eigenvalues of $S$ are distinct then those eigenspaces are 1-dimensional, so $T$ must act as a (possibly different) scalar on each eigenspace.