# Common eigenvectors implies commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck on a seemingly simple problem: if $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{N}$ are $n\times n$ and have all eigenvectors in common, then $\mathbf{MN}=\mathbf{NM}$. I can prove this if they are diagonalisable, but I am stuck on the general case. I am probably being daft, but I run into a problem when the eigenbasis does not have dimension $n$. Any help?

Comment: Basis of eigenvectors means diagonalisable.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, mistake on my part; I meant that they both have the same set of eigenvectors

Comment: Well, if they are not diagonalisable, then they need not commute.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah that would explain my frustration. Are there simple examples of, say $2\times 2$ non-diagonalisable matrices that share eigenvectors but fail to commute?

Comment: $2\times 2$ doesn't work (at least for real matrices), I think. But $4\times 4$: $$\begin{pmatrix} a & -b & 0 & 0\\ b & a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & c & -d\\ 0 & 0 & d & c \end{pmatrix}; \qquad \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & -b & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & -d \\ b & 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & d & 0 & c\end{pmatrix}$$ with generic nonzero $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wait sorry, I don't get the same eigenvectors. Compare [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Ba%2C0%2C-b%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cc%2C0%2C-d%7D%2C%7Bb%2C0%2Ca%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cd%2C0%2Cc%7D%7D+eigenvectors) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Ba%2C-b%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7Bb%2Ca%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cc%2C-d%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cd%2Cc%7D%7D+eigenvectors). Is there a mistake?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof).

Comment: I intended the matrices to be real. Generically, neither of the two matrices has any (real) eigenvectors (for unfortunate choices of $a,b,c,d$, they might have).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this is not true in the general (non-diagonalizable) case. To see why, note that for any $A$ and invertible $S$, the eigenvectors of $SAS^{-1}$ are $\{Sv \mid v \text{ eigenvector of } A\}$. If $A$ does not have a basis of eigenvectors, then $S$ may permute eigenvectors of $A$, but act freely on the remaining vectors in a basis, so that $SAS^{-1}$ does not commute with $A$. For an explicit counterexample, take

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, \; S = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \; B = SAS^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $A, B$ have the same set of eigenvectors, namely (multiples of) $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\1\end{bmatrix}$, but $AB = \!\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \ne \!\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} = BA$.