# If $A,B$ are square matrices and $A^2=A,B^2=B,AB=BA$, then calculate $\det (A-B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, diagonalization

> If $A,B$ are square matrices and $A^2=A,B^2=B,AB=BA$, then calculate $\det (A-B)$.

My solution: consider $(A-B)^3=A^3-3A^2B+3AB^2-B^3=A^3-B^3=A-B$, then $\det(A-B)=0\vee 1\vee -1$

The result of the book is the same as mine, but their solution is different. They begin: "Since $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$, $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable; moreover, since $AB=BA$, then  there exists a invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are diagonal matrices."

The statement has two parts, and I don't understand both. So I really need a specific explanation for those two parts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

For any square matrix $\;A\;$ :

$\;A^2=A\implies A(A-I)=0\implies\;$ the minimal polynomial of $\;A\;$ divides $\;x(x-1)\;$ and it is thus a product of different linear factors $\;\iff A\;$ is diagonalizable.

Also, if two matrices are diagonalizable, then they are **simultaneosly diagonalizable** iff they commute.

Comment: Could you give a proof for "if $A,B$ commute, then they are simultaneously diagonalizable"?

Comment: @TienKhaPham The proof is tricky for general $A,B$ that commute. See my answer for the case when all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct. The general problem actually appeared as a preliminary exam problem for graduate students in mathematics at UC Berkeley (a top 5 math program).

Comment: @TienKhaPham Try here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof

Answer (score 2):

If $AB = BA$, and $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, then you can find a basis matrix $P$ that simultaneously diagonalizes $A$ and $B$. To see this, consider an eigenvector $v$ of $A$. Then $A(Bv) = BAv = B \lambda v$, so $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ too, with the same eigenvalue. But if $A$ is diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues this can only happen if $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$. The argument for non-distinct eigenvalues of $A$ is a little trickier but it can be done, along the same lines.