# property of simultaneous diagonalisable matrices

Tags: matrices

If A,B and B,C and C,A are simultaneously diagonalisable matrices then is this true that A,B,C are simultaneously diagonalisable? Here $A,B,C\geq{0}$.

Comment: What does $A, B, C \geq 0$ mean?

Comment: A,B,C are positive definite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

A set of diagonalizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if that set commutes (see, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof) question).  By definition a set of matrices commutes if each pair commutes, thus a set of diagonalizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if each pair in the set is simultaneously diagonalizable.