# Subspace of symmetric commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given $W$  a subspace of real $n$-dimensional matrices which are symmetric and pairwise commuting. I have to prove that $dim(W) \leq n$.

I have read some facts about commuting matrices over an algebraic closed field, but these do not apply in this case.

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that [the matrices in the subspace are simultaneously diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof).

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the above comment, we must use the fact that the matrices must be [simultaneously (orthogonally) diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability).

That is, all matrices in the set have the form
$$
U\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ &\ddots\\ && \lambda_n} U^T
$$
for some orthogonal $U$.  The space of such matrices (for a fixed $U$) is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ with dimension $n$.