# Given two diagonalizable matrices that commute (AB = BA),is AB necessarily diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Prove or disprove: Given two diagonalizable matrices A, B that commute (AB = BA),is AB necessarily diagonalizable?

Comment: By the result described at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof , the answer is yes (product of diagonal matrices is diagonal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two matrices commutes iff they are diagonalizable simultaneously. This means that $A=PD_1P^{-1}$ and $B=PD_2P^{-1}$, where $D_1,D_2$ are diagonal matrices. This also imply that $AB$ is similar to $D_1D_2$ which is diagonal and then $AB$ is diagonalizable.