# Does such a basis exist? And how can it be proven that it does?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a square diagonal matrix.  Suppose $B$ is a square diagonalizable matrix (i.e. there is a basis $\beta$ for $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to which the linear transformation represented by $B$ is representable by a diagonal matrix).  Can we find a basis for $V$ wrt which both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal?  If so, how?

If $B$ represents some lin. transf. $T$ with resp. to the standard basis for $V$, and $B$ is diagonalizable, then there is a basis $\beta$ for $V$ with respect to which $T$ is representable by $kI$ (some diagonal matrix).  If $A$ is diagonalizable to begin with (wrt standard basis), will it also be diagonal wrt $B$ in general?  I want to say no.  How can I prove that a basis $B'$ exists with respect to which both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal?

Comment: Two matrices are simultaneusly diagonalizable only if they commutes. See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you're asking, but it should all be handled by the following theorem:

> Take any two *diagonalizable* transformations $S,T:V \to V$. There exists $\mathcal B$ for which the two matrices are both diagonal (that is, $S$ and $T$ can be *simultaneously diagonalized*) **if and only if** $ST = TS$.

For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}, \qquad B = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}
$$
they are not both diagonal, but they are both **diagonalizable** with $AB = BA$.  If we take a base such as $\mathcal B = \{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$, we find that the matrix of these transformations relative to the basis is 
$$
A = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&1} \qquad B = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}
$$
on the other hand, if we had
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}, \qquad B = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&5}
$$
we would find that there is no such basis, since $AB \neq BA$.