# A question matrix multiplication commutative?

Tags: linear-algebra

1. If $A$ and $B$ two matrices of order $n\times n$ such that $AB=I$ then $A$ and $B$ are commutative and
2. Give any two reasons for A and B commutative.

I know what

... one matrix is the Identity matrix.

... one matrix is the Zero matrix.

... both matrices are 2×2 rotation matrices. (basically case #2)

... both matrices are Diagonal matrices.

how to prove part one

Comment: I think you shall say that is B is a right inverse of A, then B is the inverse of A. This is an indirect consequence of the nullity-rank.

Comment: The rest of your question is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: This might be very helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof