# $ST=TS$ leads to diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Preparing for GRE math subject and I come across this problem:

> $S$ and $T$ are linear transformations of a finite space $V$, $ST=TS$, each eigenspace of $S$ is one-dimensional, which of the followings are/is correct?
>
> 1. Each eigenvector of $S$ is also $T$'s
> 2. Each eigenvector of $T$ is also $S$'s
> 3. $T$ is diagonalizable

Since each eigenspace of $S$ is of one dimension, $S$ should be diagonalizable, but the relationship of $ST=TS$ is hard to interpret. Usually matrix is not communicative, $ST=TS$ should contain some kind of important information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneously Diagonalizable Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof)

Comment: If $ST=TS$, and $x$ is an eigenvector of $S$, then $STx=TSx=\lambda Tx$, so $Tx$ is an eigenvector of $S$.