# Operators simultaneously diagonalizables

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $f$ and $g$ linear operators in $V$ which are both diagonalizables. We say that $f$ and $g$ are simultaneously diagonalizables if there exists a basis $\alpha$ of $V$ in which both $\mathop {\left[f\right]} \nolimits_\alpha ^\alpha$  as $\left[ g \right]_\alpha ^\alpha $ are diagonal matrices. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are simultaneously diagonalizables if and only if $f$ and $g$ commute.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof?rq=1

Comment: This is in all the linear algebra books....