# $S, T$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V a a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and let $S, T ~\in~ End(V)$ both diagonalizable and that $[S, T] = 0$. Show that $S, T$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.
I've tried to show that $V_{\lambda}$ is $S-stable$ by descomposing $V = \oplus_{\lambda \in Spec(T)} $ but I get nowhere.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: this and every variation of it is done in the first Horn and Johnson book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/prove-that-simultaneously-diagonalizable-matrices-commute

Comment: Thanks, I didn´t see those.