# Show that $B$ is diagonalizable if If $AB=BA$ and $A$ has distinct real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

We were asked to prove the following:

Let $ A $ be an $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct real eigenvalues. If $AB=BA$, show that $B$ is diagonalizable.

It was suggested I show that an eigenvector of $A$ is also an eigenvector of $B$. I am both having trouble doing this and failing to see how I would complete the proof after. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is (a weaker version of) part (b) of the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof.  It is also a consequence of the statement in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65012/if-matrices-a-and-b-commute-a-with-distinct-eigenvalues-then-b-is-a-po And this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46544/why-does-a-diagonalization-of-a-matrix-b-with-the-basis-of-a-commuting-matrix-a?lq=1

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/matrices-commute-common-set-of-eigenvectors?lq=1 where the accepted answer can be adapted to answer your question.

Comment: Hey Jonas, I still don't understand how it is that if $v$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to some eigenvalue $ \lambda $, that $A(Bv)= \lambda Bv$ implies that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $B$. I was wondering if you could clear that up for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a comment:

> I still don't understand how it is that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to some eigenvalue $\lambda$, that $A(Bv)=\lambda Bv$ implies that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $B$.

If we see that this is true, then we will be able to conclude that $B$ is diagonalized by a basis of eigenvectors for $A$.

It is true because the eigenspace of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, $\{x:Ax=\lambda x\}$, is one dimensional by the hypothesis that $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues.  The equation $A(Bv)=\lambda Bv$ says that $Bv$ is in this space, which is spanned by $v$. Therefore there exists a scalar $c$ such that $Bv=cv$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much. I just wasn't considering the one dimensionality of the eigenspace. Thank you very much Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

So $A$ is diagonalizable with n distinct  elements on its main diagonal, $A=diag$ $(a_1,..., a_n)$. Let $B=(b_{ij})$, do the multiplication for both sides of $AB=BA$ and use component-wise correspondence for matrix equality. Now you see the elements off the main diagonal of B must be zero