# $AB=BA$ and $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues. Prove $B$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:**

A and B are matrices size $n\times n$

given $AB=BA$ and A has n eigenvalues, prove $B$ is diagonalizable.

I would have written what I tried to do, but It's really nothing worth reading..

Any help would appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: This is not true in general. $B=A$ satisfies $AB=BA$ but doesn't necessarily imply $A$ is diagonal.. Unless you mean $B$ is *diagonalizable*..

Comment: Do you mean that $B$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: If you really mean diagonalizable, have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285546/if-ab-ba-show-that-b-is-diagonalizable

Comment: Yes, yes! sorry, diagonalizable... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
if $AB=BA$ the set of eigenvectors of $A$ are $B$-stable.

details:

indeed, if $Ax=ux$, then $ A(Bx) = BAx = u(Bx)
$ and $Bx\propto x$, because $\{ y| Ay=uy
\}$ is a line which contains $x$ (because $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues).

Let $(e_i)$ be a basis of eigenvectors of $A$. Then in this basis, $B$ is diagonal as well.

Comment: What do "eigenvectors' set is stable" mean? And what does $\;Bx\propto x\;$ mean, too?

Comment: it means that is $v $ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $Bv$ too. The second one means that there is a scalar $l$ such as $Bx=lx$

Comment: Uh? Did you mean that $\;v\;$ eigenvector of $\;A\implies Bv\;$ also an eigenvector of $\;A\;$ ?

Comment: The french are going to drive me crazy with their notations and names...!

Comment: Look at after "details": I show that if $Ax=ux$ then $A(Bx)=u(Bx)$. In other words: the set $\{ x: Ax=ux\}$ is $B$-stable.