# What is the interpretation of a "commuting block"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose two square $n\times n$ matrices, $A$ and $B$, do not commute.
$$[A,B] = 0$$
However, suppose their commutator has a block of all 0's, i.e.
\begin{align}
[A, B] = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
* & \dotsm & * & * & \dotsm&*\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots&\vdots \\
* & \dotsm & * & *&\dotsm & *\\
* & \dotsm & * & 0&\dotsm & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots& \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
*& \dotsm & *& 0&\dotsm & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

then how can this be interpreted in terms of the respective eigenvectors of the matrices? In trying to understand this I reviewed the accepted answer to ["Why does a diagonalization of a matrix B with the basis of a commuting matrix A give a block diagonal matrix?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46567/409450). Here's my thinking so far,

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ lying in the subspace $V_0 = (v_k, v_{k+1}, ..., v_n)$ that corresponds to the $\mathbf{0}$ (zero matrix) block of $[A,B]$. Then
\begin{align}
[A,B]v = (AB-BA)v
\end{align}
will necessarily be orthogonal to $v$, and be supported entirely in the subspace $V_1 = (v_1, v_{2}, ..., v_{k-1})$.

However we cannot make the analogous statement to the fully commuting case, like that the vector $v'=Av$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with the same eigenvalue as $\lambda$. Maybe this isn't the right meaning of "commuting block"?